# Strange "invalid conversion from <type> to <type>" error

Tags: c++, winapi, casting

Here is output:

```
g++ -DDEBUG -DUNITTEST -IC:/Users/Steven/Dropbox/Programming/entropy_p5_makefile/cpp/game/../include/ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o Input.o ..\Input.cpp
..\Input.cpp: In function 'void mousehookCustomRoutine(E_thread*, void*)':
..\Input.cpp:78:93: error: invalid conversion from 'LRESULT (*)(int, WPARAM, LPARAM)' to 'LRESULT (*)(int, WPARAM, LPARAM)'
..\Input.cpp:78:93: error:   initializing argument 2 of 'void* SetWindowsHookExA(int, LRESULT (*)(int, WPARAM, LPARAM), HINSTANCE__*, DWORD)'
Build error occurred, build is stopped
```

This is the code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    //...
}

void mousehookCustomRoutine(E_thread *me, void *arg = (void *)&MouseHookProc) {
    // arg is the ptr to LL Mouse Routine

    me->sendMessage(0x14,me,(void*)GetCurrentThreadId());
    // send message to self in order for my parent to know how to identify me via threadID
    HHOOK mousehook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, (LRESULT (*)(int,WPARAM,LPARAM))arg,NULL, 0); // I am line 78
    if (mousehook == NULL) printf("Mousehook error %lu\n",GetLastError());
    //...
}
```

It makes no sense because I am casting to the exact type that it expects to receive, there aren't any qualifiers or anything that are different. What could possibly be going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't cast function pointers to `void *`. It is never safe to invoke a function of one type after casting it to another, and so there's rarely, if ever, a need to make them `void *`.

Second, probably you're seeing a difference in calling conventions. The type of the hook parameter is, properly stated, `(LRESULT (CALLBACK *) (int, WPARAM, LPARAM))`, or simply `HOOKPROC`. The prototype of the function should look like `LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHookProc(int, WPARAM, LPARAM)`. Most likely gcc doesn't pretty-print the calling-convention specifier, but does check for it when checking type equivalence. Subtle problems like this are another reason not to cast function pointers - had you used a `(HOOKPROC)` cast, you would have had no compile-time error, but could have crashed at runtime .... [but only on certain versions of windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/06/10161590.aspx).

Comment: Okay. I will look into trying to get it to work by specifying the calling convention. Thanks for the warning against casting to `void*`. The problem is that the `mousehookCustomRoutine` function is being sent to a thread generator, i.e. it is the function which defines the thread. As such this function needs to have a type which can be passed to the thread starter. I can allocate a struct which holds the function pointer without casting it, and pass a pointer to that via the `void * arg`, but I figured since pointers are all the same size why not just use the `void*` to hold the value?

Comment: @Steven, ah, a thread parameter might be an exception. But then you must be VERY careful that your types are what you expect. I would wrap the thread creation in a function that does check the type of the incoming callback before casting to `void *`

Comment: Okay, my function which initiates the thread will be defined as requiring the very same function pointer type for its argument, and it goes on to create a thread by passing it in. It seems to me that if I send this function the wrong type (including call convention) it will complain for the exact same reason that this question's error popped up.

Comment: Could you quickly explain why `CALLBACK` i.e. the stdcall declaration is placed inside of the parenthesis? I threw out `CALLBACK` when writing the type because I wasnt sure where to put it. Of course it caused this error, but now that i know where to put it, I'm wondering why it's put there. BTW it compiles just fine now. :)

Comment: @Steven, CALLBACK applies to the function as a whole and defines the calling convention (ie, how to pass arguments and return values) for the function. For silly historical reasons Windows has multiple calling conventions, and this causes all kinds of confusion.

Comment: I understand that, but I'm wondering about the right place to locate the declaration of the calling convention. Seems it's supposed to be `__attribute__((__stdcall__))` for GCC and `__stdcall` for other compilers, and it also goes at the end for GCC while it goes before the declaration with the others... and i can't find anything that mentions how that all translates to where it goes when using with a function ptr declaration..... I guess I am going to not worry about it once I get it working. It probably will work if I stick it just about anywhere.

Comment: I haven't used GCC for Win32, so I can't really comment on where to put it. However Microsoft's headers put it before the function name, so if GCC can handle those it should be able to handle it before the function name.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is omitting the calling convention from the error message -- `SetWindowsHookEx` wants a `LRESULT (__stdcall *)(int,WPARAM,LPARAM)`, but you're passing it a `LRESULT (__cdecl *)(int,WPARAM,LPARAM)`.